# BufferedReader and BufferedWriter in Java null

Tags: java, bufferedreader

**Client.java**

```
try {
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        received = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("In-Cmd = " + received);

} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

**Server.java**

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));
    System.out.println("Out-Cmd = STOP");
    bw.write("stop");
    bw.newLine();
} finally {
    try {
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {}
}
```

So, what happen is that I have this GUI where the client can upload the file from their local hardrive to the server, and then we will copy the file and store them in the server.

I can send BufferWriter from Client to Server no problem at all, but when I want to do from Server to Client I always receive `null`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you check for exceptions?

Comment: @galuano1 nothing appear in the console at all :(

I only see the output says : `In-Cmd: null`

Comment: Thats because you are catching the exceptions and printing nothing.

Comment: @galuano1 Oh wow. I'm so stupid I thought I did :S